# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'console' or its corresponding type declarations. 3 import { Console } from 'console';

Tags: angular

src/app/welcome/welcome.component.ts:3:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'console' or its corresponding type declarations.  3 import { Console } from 'console';

I am getting the above Error meassage while doing "ng serve". can any please help me out?

Comment: Why would you need to import console?  Console is already available without an import, Go to the line 3 of your `src/app/welcome/welcome.component.ts` file, delete the line `import { Console } from 'console';` Now look for `Console` in your code and replace it `console`

Comment: console is a global object, you don't need to import it. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, as someone mentioned above, you should remove `import {console} from 'console';`. It will be solved.

Comment: I had the same problem and code was working before. So I'm puzzled how it suddenly stopped working and why the OP and yourself and myself all had the import statement there to begin with.

Comment: I had the same issue, an import in my ts file. I accidentally typed 'console' as 'Console', i.e. with a capital 'C', and this automatically added the import which broke the console.log statement. Took a while to spot it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you should verify is that you have types properly installed

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```